# aspnetmvc6 não consigo atualizar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

to testando o visual studo 2015 criei um projeto asp.net mvc e to querendo atualiza ele para usar a nova versão 6 beta. mas to com um erro aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu resolvo isso?

mandei atualizar o entity framework deu isso

```
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.2'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.2'.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\amj\Source\Repos\Teste\WebApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\init.ps1'.
Removing 'EntityFramework 6.1.1' from WebApplication1.
Added file 'Web.config'.
Removed reference 'EntityFramework.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Removed reference 'EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully removed 'EntityFramework 6.1.1' from WebApplication1.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.1.2' to WebApplication1.
For adding package 'EntityFramework 6.1.2' to project 'WebApplication1' that targets 'net451',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net45'
>> Content files are being added from 'content' (not framework-specific)
Added file 'Web.config'.
Added reference 'EntityFramework' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added reference 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.1.2' to WebApplication1.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\amj\Source\Repos\Teste\WebApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\install.ps1'.

Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.1.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.1.1'.
```

ai eu tentei o asp.net mvc:

```
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1'.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Added file 'Web.config'.
Removed reference 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Added file 'Web.config'.
Removed reference 'System.Web.Helpers.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Removed reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Removed reference 'System.Web.Razor.dll' from project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' from WebApplication1.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1' to WebApplication1.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' to WebApplication1.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' to project 'WebApplication1' that targets 'net451',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net45'
Added reference 'System.Web.Razor' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' to WebApplication1.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2' to WebApplication1.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2' to project 'WebApplication1' that targets 'net451',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net45'
>> Content files are being added from 'Content' (not framework-specific)
Added file 'Web.config'.
Added reference 'System.Web.Helpers' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added reference 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2' to WebApplication1.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' to WebApplication1.
For adding package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' to project 'WebApplication1' that targets 'net451',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net45'
>> Content files are being added from 'Content' (not framework-specific)
Added file 'Web.config'.
Added reference 'System.Web.Mvc' to project 'WebApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' to WebApplication1.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1'.
```

Mas me deu este erro:

```
...
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta1' to WebApplication1.
Install failed. Rolling back...
...
```

Comment: Já tentou usar uma versão do Framework mais baixo, como a 4.5.1, por exemplo?

Comment: oi cigano já tentei sim acontece a mesma coisa obrigado

Comment: Nenhum dos dois logs citados aparenta ser um erro, parece ser apenas logs de instalação, já o erro `Could not install package` parece ser um conflito com a versão beta, ou algo do gênero, como você está usando o comando `install-package`?

Comment: o primeiro eu mostrei que deu certo, o segundo dá erro de Install failed. Rolling back... eu to usando o nuget do visual studio tem uma funcao nele que faz tudo isto automaticamente pra vc obrigado guilherme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso que você deseja. Não é possível atualizar um projeto MVC 5 pra MVC 6.

Se você quer testar um projeto com ASP.NET MVC 6, precisa criar um novo projeto `ASP.NET 5 (vNext)`. Atualmente existem 2 templates: *Empty* e *Starter Web*.

O mais recomendado é você criar o segundo: **ASP.NET 5 Starter Web**.

Comment: vou fazer isso obrigado

Comment: Futuramente vai dar. Por enquanto, com tudo na fase beta, ainda não é possível.