# Como fazer um Hello World no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Eu já programo mas estou começando com C# e ASP.NET MVC. Eu queria fazer um programa *Hello World* e ir adicionando coisas aos poucos como sempre fiz com qualquer linguagem que aprendi.

Achei que criando um projeto no Visual Studio ele criaria um *Hello World*. mas ele criou uma aplicação inteira, tem diversas pastas, mais de 200 arquivos, e isso é muito doido.

Eu queria algo bem simples eu sei que não dá para fazer só um `Console.Write("Hello World")`, mas qual seria o código mais simples possível do MVC? Eu queria ter códigos bem pequenos e com poucos arquivos, queria um projeto bem pequenininho, quase vazio.

Toda pesquisa que faço dá códigos muito grandes.

Comment: Você poderia acrescentar na pergunta qual o procedimento que usou no VS para criar esse projeto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Para criar uma estrutura simples para um site ASP.NET MVC**

O mais simples para um Hello World.

Algumas pastas são mandatórias, como é o caso das pastas Controllers, Models e Views.

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

Crie um novo projeto ASP.Net Web Application:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione as referências básicas do MVC (bibliotecas, Global.asax, RouteConfig e etc.)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resultado, você terá um solution muito básica. Uma que se você executar F5, não vai exibir página nenhuma, pois não existem páginas, mas existe a aplicação Asp.NET. Veja como fica a estrutura: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem views, sem controles, sem pasta de scripts (onde geralmente temos arquivos javascript) e sem pasta de imagens, ou seja, sem arquivos "desnecessários".

**Para criar um Hello World com uma View**

Agora basta você criar um Controller novo :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E uso o MVC 5 Controller - Empty
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que foi criado um controller, que chamei de DefaultController, bem simples:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora temos um Controller com uma action chamada Index, mas ainda precisamos criar uma view para essa Action. Para isso, basta clicar com o botão direito em cima da Action Index e escolher Add View. Preencher a tela abaixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como resultado você tem um arquivo cshtml que é a view da action Index da Controller DefaultController.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora basta iniciar o debug, F5, e você verá uma linda página em branco.
Para incluir o Hello World, basta escrever no HTML do arquivo Index.cshtml a palavra Hello World.

**Se nem quero criar uma View para meu Hello World**

Se você nem quiser ter um arquivo de View, pode optar por fazer um Hello World como o Laerte demonstrou em sua resposta:

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Assim, basta iniciar a aplicação e navegar até `http://localhost:<suaPorta>/Default/HelloWorld`

Comment: eu vou tentar isso acho que voce entendeu o que eu quero

Comment: agora eu consegui o que eu queria, nem precisou do model. só ficou uma dúvida tem algum desses poucos arquivos que sobraram que dá para apagar sem medo?

Comment: Você quer mesmo zero arquivos hein? Mas você pode eliminar os arquivos `.config` (Web.config, package.config). Você precisa do Global.asax (principal da aplicação, onde a aplicação é iniciada). O RouteConfig.cs só se você colocar no Global.asax.

Comment: foi o que eu imaginei não precisa ser zero rsrs mas quero começar com o mínimo e ir colocando mais conforme eu preciso e ir aprendendo do zero

Answer (score 8):

Com Visual Studio aberto pressione: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  ou pode simplesmente criar um **Novo Projeto**, selecione a aba Web e selecione o ASP MVC 4 Web Application, como mostrado na imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Depois na próxima janela você escolhe **Internet Application**, com o arquivo HomeController aberto você vai adicionar o código abaixo, como mostrado na imagem, depois é só executar o programa e acessar o método pela URL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por padrão quando você cria uma **ASP MVC Web Application**, ele também cria um Controller padrão *("HomeController")*, você pode criar uma **Action** que é um método dentro do **Controller**:

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Assim basta você acessar a URL pelo seu servidor local: **/Home/HelloWorld** e verá na tela.

Comment: nao tem como começar sem esses 200 arquivos ai do lado?

Comment: Tem, na segunda tela ao invés de escolher o template "Internet Application", escolha: "Empty", a partir disso você pode criar seus próprios Controllers, Views, etc. Usando o template "Empty" (vazio) ele só cria as pastas essências.

Comment: por exemplo sem mvc eu posso ter um arquivo program.cs e mais uns outros arquivos do projeto uns 3 ou 4 só mas o programa mesmo é só um arquivo. entendeu? quero saber de algo que dá para fazer com poucos arquivos, sei lá, com 10, 15, não com 200. nao consegui fazer nada nesse link que vc passou acho que isso é pago

Comment: É, agora para baixar as apostila da K19 tem que fazer cadastro, mas creio que você esteja confundido a forma de trabalhar com MVC, não é algo como uma aplicação de Console, cada Controller é como se fosse um "tela" do sistema, e cada action é uma funcionalidade da "tela", pra você trabalhar com MVC você precisa ter um Controller que é onde vai ter as Actions que executaram ações, como salvar, excluir, etc.

Comment: isso eu entendi por isso eu falei que nao espero que seja um arquivo so com uma classe e um metodo mas 200 arquivos é muita coisa, queria algo menor, o menor possivel, eu duvido que nao de para fazer menor que isso

Comment: @fabianorastone O menor template que eu tenho conhecimento é o "Empty", a única forma de fazer o que você quer é você criando um projeto e adicionar as referências depois e sua pergunta é como mostrar um "Olá, mundo", se você tem outras dúvidas faça outra pergunta.

Comment: mas isso nao é um hello world, eu nao perguntei como escrever hello world na tela, perguntei como fazer um codigo pequeno que faça só o minimo necessario, o codigo que ta la no visual studio tem um monte de coisa que ate eu que nao sei nada sei que nao precisa

Comment: O que tem lá são as Actions, você pode remover, ou como mencionei criar um projeto com o template vazio e cria seus próprios controllers.

Comment: Aqui o print da Solution com o template vazio: http://i.stack.imgur.com/56fgE.png apenas o essencial, agora os Controllers, Views, Models, você mesmo cria.

Comment: @Laerte talvez o que ele queira é não usar MVC, talvez ele nem saiba o que é MVC, no caso Fabiano você pode criar um `aspx` e trabalhar a partir deste ponto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente está difícil chegar num acordo no que ele realmente quer.

Comment: eu quero so usar o asp.net mvc com o minimo possivel, sem esses 200 arquivos, eu sei que vou precisar de no minimo 3 arquivos para fazer o M, o V, e o C, eu vi como eles funcionam, eu vi o projeto exemplo do visual studio, eu acho que entendi. eu acho que só esses 3 arquivos não dá precisa de outros e é isso q eu queria saber quais arquivos são obrigatoriso, quais classes são obrigatórias p/ fazer só o "hello word" aparecer mais nada mas do jeito asp.net mvc. nao quero autentica nada nao quero que fique bonitinho nao quero que faça mais nada

Comment: O @Laerte já mostrou como fazer o que você quer, crie um projeto com a template Empty/Vazio, veja a imagem que ele postou alguns comentário acima: http://i.stack.imgur.com/56fgE.png

Comment: esse template empty vai criar só uma classe sem anda ou vai fazer um projeto asp.net mvc mínimo?

Comment: Vai criar uma estrutura padrão para você conseguir utilizar MVC normalmente, leia-se: o básico para funcionar.

Comment: o meu erro é que tava criando o tempolate errado o guilherme resolveu

Answer (score 2):

O MVC não é algo especifico do ASP.NET, tanto que é totalmente possível trabalhar sem MVC, pois ele não é uma obrigatoriedade, é apenas um padrão de **projeto** de software. Para se ter uma noção disto veja que existem outros tipos de "padrões":

- [MVP Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)
- [MVVM Model View ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

Em linguagens como PHP, quem não usa framework, raramente irá usar MVC, mas isto não é a questão da linguagem.

É quase impossível criar um MVC (no seu caso parece que é um MVC e Rotas) com 3 arquivos no *asp.net mvc* como você pediu, pois é necessário várias configurações, como um exemplo o arquivo `Web.config` e todos esses arquivos ao qual você se refere, são partes das configurações necessárias para que tudo funcione e você *não é obrigado* a entender um por um.

Portanto o *mínimo possível* ainda sim irá gerar ainda sim muitos arquivos (ressaltando: você não é obrigado a entender o significado de cada um deles).

Vou ser sincero eu até entendo você, sou muito parecido, gosto de estar no "controle", evitar deixar que IDEs façam o meu trabalho (acho que é assim que você pensa), mas infelizmente parece não haver material suficientemente claro de como criar o seu próprio MVC (que trabalhe com "rotas" é claro), a principio editar o arquivo `HomeController.cs` seria o mais correto, porém se você necessita realmente de alternativas, acredito que isto possa lhe ajudar:

- [asp.net do zero](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/aspnet-from-scratch-mvc--net-14071)
- [aspx migração para mvc](https://github.com/junxy/aspx-migration-to-mvc-example) (Não testei)

> Nota: Infelizmente em português não fui capaz de encontrar nada.

Se você quiser tentar o MVVM:

- [asp.net mvc mvvm criando uma sessão de produtos](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3031/aspnet-mvc_mvvm-criando-uma-sessao-de-produtos.aspx)

Comment: vou ver seus links, eu entendo o padrão de projeto mvc eu entendo que não dá para fazer com 1 arquivo mas o outro guilerme mostrou que dá para fazer bem menor do que u tava fazendo

Comment: eu nao pedi 3 arquivos, eu sei que precisa de mais mas 200 era muita coisa mas tirando os arquivos do projeto agora tá com 4 arquivos é melhor do que eu esperava e acho que que dá para fazer com 3 se não fizer o view como o guilherme falou

Comment: O 3 arquivos eu li em algum comentário, ao momento que você deixar de fazer o view, você terá mais dificuldade ao trabalhar com as respostas das "rotas"

Answer (score 1):

Você criou um projeto Web MVC. Comece com um simples **Class Library**.

Dê uma olhadinha nesse tutorial da Microsoft [Hello World Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa288463%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

E se quiser começar bem mesmo, já estuda o novo [ASP.NET vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext), você vai precisar baixar o Visual Studio 2015 Preview ou o [KVM](https://github.com/aspnet/kvm). Ele (o Visual Studio) também tem um projeto do tipo Class Library e já vai te ajudar a trabalhar com as novas formas de recuperar as dependências. (Bower e o grunt como JS Task Runner)

Comment: eu to tentando usar o vnext mas deu um erro ja perguntei sobre isso mas ninguem respondeu. eu queria comecar fzer do jeito que vc falou e ir colocando coisas extras ao poucos tipo colocar um model bem simples depois um contoller bem simples e um view bem simples e queria ver se so isso funcionaria

Comment: Você está usando Visual Studio? Se sim, qual a versão?

Comment: 2015 olha só http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45248/aspnetmvc6-n%C3%A3o-consigo-atualizar#45248

Comment: A resposta que você recebeu lá é valida. Para migrar um projeto de ASP.Net 5 para o 6 não é muito simples. Ainda mais que agora o VS tem um novo compiler. Vai em File > New Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET 5 Class Library.

Comment: vou tentar isso