# Como criar uma aplicação do zero em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou estudando sobre o  *Asp.Net MVC* e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45417/como-fazer-um-hello-world-no-asp-net-mvc) já obtive uma boa base de como começar do zero com Empty, pois não tenho encontrado um bom tutorial de como começar.

**Meu problema é o seguinte:**

Tenho esse form que está no [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x4g5e8a/) e que tenho que adicionar essas informações em um banco de dados, ou seja, teria que obter os dados -> criar uma 
Query de insert e salvar no banco.

Gostaria de entender por onde passaria todo  o código entre o *Controller* e o *Model* até a inserção no banco.

Se possível com exemplo com códigos.

Comment: Apenas complementando a resposta do @Cigano, talvez [este tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn877997.aspx) possa lhe ajudar a entender como fazer isso. Se tiver alguma dúvida, avise que elaboro uma resposta.

Comment: Assim que possivel estarei lendo sobre @Randrade. Vlw demais. Mais se quiser arrisca uma resposta manda ver.

Comment: Olá, pra você que está iniciando eu te indico que assista as video aulas do Cleyton Ferrari > https://www.youtube.com/user/cleytonferrari/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tenho uma introdução melhor pra você](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220).

> Gostaria de entender por onde passaria todo o código entre o *Controller* e o *Model* até a inserção no banco.

Bom, você acaba de responder uma parte da sua própria pergunta. Vou agora esmiuçar mais tecnicamente.

Seu formulário tem uma *action*, que é o mesmo nome do método no *Controller* (que, aliás, também chamamos de *Action*). Por exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAcao(MeuViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

Seu formulário, no caso, precisaria estar assim:

```
<form id="form1" action="/MeuController/MinhaAcao">
```

Os nomes dos campos refletem aquilo que o *Model* ou *ViewModel* recebe. Por exemplo, seu campo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNome" name="name" placeholder="Título">
```

O `name` dele é `"name"`, então o *ViewModel* precisa ter:

```
public class MeuViewModel
{
    public String name { get; set; } // O campo precisa ter exatamente o mesmo valor do atributo "name" do formulário
    ...
}
```

A atribuição dos valores enviados é feita de forma automática através de uma funcionalidade do ASP.NET MVC chamada *Model Binding*.

No caso, seu formulário está errado, porque possui dois `<input>`s com o mesmo `"name"` (com, aliás, o valor "name").

Supondo agora que você corrigiu seu formulário e fez um teste para enviar dados para o *Controller*. Se você preencheu um *ViewModel* e está usando Entity Framework, terá que preencher um *Model* também para inserir ou atualizar a informação no banco de dados, ou você pode receber um *Model* preenchido do formulário diretamente. Alguns discordam que isso seja seguro, então algumas correntes desencorajam o uso de *Models* diretamente em formulários. Opinativamente falando, acho seguro porque há maneiras de verificar o *Model* antes de inserir, usando, por exemplo, [`[Bind]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Se você não estiver usando Entity Framework, basta ler os valores das propriedades do *Model* ou *ViewModel* e inserir no banco da maneira com que quiser.

Não vou alongar a resposta sobre o Entity Framework porque não precisa. Se quiser saber mais, faça outra pergunta ou manifeste-se por comentários.

Comment: Quando você diz: `Se você não estiver usando Entity Framework, basta ler os valores das propriedades do Model ou ViewModel e inserir no banco da maneira com que quiser.` penso em criar uma classe no model que receba como Parâmetro o ViewModel e faça a inserção, seria o ideal? E se eu usasse Ajax seria a mesma ideia?

Comment: Não. *Models* não são bons para inserir no banco. Eu implementaria um repositório genérico e passaria a classe pra ele. [Um exemplo está aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/qual-seria-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-fazer-um-crud-para-um-framework-da-maneira-mai/5658#5658).

Comment: Muito obrigado @Cigano, concerteza me agregou bastante a resposta.